# Date from server to client getting changed

Tags: javascript, java

I have server using Indian timezone and client is on Chicago timezone.I'm sending data from server as a JSON. Date coming from server is 25-07-2019 (1563993000000 as JSON string). When i'm converting this date in javascript using "new Date(1563993000000);", it becomes "24-07-2019". How to convert server date to client side using server timezone?
I'm working on Angular.

Comment: Would it be an option to just send `25-07-2019` or `2019-07-25`?

Comment: A quick and dirty way to change the timezone is to simply add the number of milliseconds. Chicago and India are 10 hours apart so just add `10 * 3600 * 1000` to the number before plugging it into `Date`. OTOH timestamps are universal, and this will effectively shift the timestamp by ten hours. So the proper approach to this problem is to use UTC time on the server and convert all other points in time accordingly.

Comment: If you can change the server code, then while returning the date from server convert to the Time zone you desire. Or else you can user moment library to update date using let myDate = moment.tz("2017-10-27 4:00:00 AM", "America/Chicago");

Comment: Why not send "25-07-2019" as a string if you want that exact string to be displayed? 1563993000000 is the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch (1970 UTC) and corresponds to 2019-07-24T18:30:00Z. Conversions from/to a local date depends on time zone. The local timezone will be used unless an explicit time zone is given.

Comment: Just use UTC-based times for all storage and interchange - timezones are only for _presentation_ purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The date coming from the server is incorrect, according to the timestamp provided the date should be

```
1563993000 converts to Wednesday July 24, 2019 13:30:00 (pm) in time zone America/Chicago (CDT)
```

you can convert the date to correct time stamp by specifying the timezone

```
new Date(1563993000000).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Chicago"})
```

https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1563993000000&tz=America%2FChicago